# TextField inside DisclosureGroup is not focusable

Tags: swift, swiftui, focus

Consider this view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var justSomeStr = ""
    @State private var isShowingSheet = false
    var body: some View {
        DisclosureGroup {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                TextField("Hello, world!", text: $justSomeStr)
                Button("Just a button") {
                    isShowingSheet.toggle()
                }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
            }
        } label: {
            Text("Disclosure")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Despite its simplicity the user is not able to edit `TextField`. It just doesn't respond. What's interesting is that if we remove the `Button` everything begins to work fine.
Xcode 14.0.1, iOS 15.

Comment: I have checked with the same code and its working perfectly my end with existence of button.

Comment: What's your iOS version @HardikShekhat? I confirm that on iOS16 simulator everything works fine, but on iOS15 device it doesn't.

Comment: Ohh yes I have checked on iOS 16 version. let me check with iOS 15.

Comment: Its working with iOS 15.6 version. Does it specific to iOS 15.0 only?

Comment: Thank you @HardikShekhat for your help. I guess you are right. It is a glitch that shows up somewhere from 15.0 to 15.5 (or lower).